# Web storage for graphic data

Tags: photography

I need good web/cloud (paid/free) storage for my graphic work. It's lots of data with photos and videos too. Any ideas?

Comment: In it's current form, this question is extremely broad. Could you specify some additional details, like the size, frequency, necessity for others to view, format types, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) and [skydrive](http://www.windowslive.co.uk/skydrive)